# How to detect two animated objects intersection in reanimated 2?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-reanimated-v2

I'm having an animated object, that can zoom, drag and rotate. What is the best way to detect its collision with other object or border? What I tried so far:

`onLayout` doesn't fire on reanimated events.

`useAnimatedReaction` crashes on attempts to use references (created with either `useRef` or `useAnimatedRef`) inside of it, thus cannot use `.measure`, `.measureLayout` or reanimated `measure` inside of it.

`useEffect` (with dependencies of zoom, rotate and drag shared values) doesn't fire until the gesture is done. Value created with `useDerivedValue` doesn't help in this case either.

Here is the sample project:
https://github.com/topheroes/TestReanimatedIntersection

Please advice